# Postgis - Check if a Point is inside Polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis, hasura

I am trying to use the ST_Intersection function to intersect a point by city polyogn but I am having no luck (Hasura + Postgresql)

```
create table "public"."cities"(
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326) 
  //other colmuns
);
```

then i added a row with multipolygon of my city :

```
INSERT INTO "public"."cities"
VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((
5.334 36.213,5.335 36.22,5.356 36.225,5.365 36.233,5.371 36.232,5.378 36.237,5.387 36.24,5.39 36.243,5.395 36.244,5.398 36.248,5.406 36.249,5.413 36.253,5.421 36.25,5.431 36.249,5.435 36.246,5.433 36.24,5.434 36.239,5.433 36.231,5.44 36.232,5.445 36.23,5.447 36.227,5.453 36.227,5.457 36.229,5.462 36.227,5.477 36.231,5.482 36.238,5.49 36.238,5.491 36.24,5.495 36.241,5.503 36.241,5.506 36.237,5.506 36.234,5.509 36.231,5.51 36.225,5.509 36.216,5.502 36.211,5.502 36.207,5.498 36.202,5.498 36.199,5.502 36.194,5.502 36.183,5.499 36.18,5.499 36.177,5.497 36.175,5.492 36.174,5.487 36.169,5.481 36.17,5.481 36.163,5.478 36.159,5.475 36.158,5.476 36.154,5.472 36.148,5.472 36.145,5.469 36.142,5.452 36.141,5.44 36.133,5.438 36.13,5.433 36.13,5.43 36.138,5.42 36.137,5.418 36.139,5.41 36.136,5.406 36.136,5.402 36.139,5.392 36.137,5.384 36.138,5.369 36.13,5.364 36.132,5.364 36.135,5.346 36.138,5.345 36.143,5.35 36.151,5.347 36.156,5.347 36.164,5.343 36.171,5.343 36.175,5.338 36.18,5.336 36.187,5.333 36.191,5.334 36.194,5.333 36.201,5.336 36.205,5.334 36.213
)))', 4326) );
```

But when i run this query with a Point is the center of city, i doesn't return any data.

```
select * 
from "public"."cities"
where ST_Intersects("public"."cities"."geom", ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(36.1917 5.4235)', 4326));
```

**UPDATE :** 
I stored the polygon in long-lat, but i was querying with lat-long Point, my mistake

Comment: the point is in lat-long, while it should be in long-lat

Comment: @JGH and this also apply to polygon and multipolygon ?

Comment: Either the point OR the polygon is wrong. See that the coordinates are not in the same order in both cases

Comment: @JGH you have a point, i didn't even notice it, Thanks so much